# Flutter TabIndicator custom design

Tags: flutter, tabbar

How can I get those topRight and TopLeft rounded corners for TabIndicator?[image]

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar/indicator.html

Comment: @pskink I am specifically asking about those rounded corders.

Comment: so you are not using `TabBar` widget?

Comment: I am using ```TabBar```. I just want to customize the TabBar's indicator(Rounded corners). I found nothing in the documentation regarding the issue.

Comment: You can always create your custom tab indicators. Have a look at this : https://mightytechno.com/style-tabs-in-flutter-app/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Using ```BoxDecoration``` will cover the whole Tab's background. In my case, the indicator is only an **Underline** under the tab. If you can create this design, please provide the code that produces this design.

Comment: get `ShapeBuilder` from [here](https://gist.github.com/pskink/41bbb30e1d06de078bf59a10341ac29c) and use it `indicator: ShapeDecoration(
color: Colors.red,
shape: ShapeBuilder(tabBuilder),
),` where `tabBuilder` is a function like this: `Path tabBuilder(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
final r = Alignment.bottomCenter.inscribe(Size(rect.width, 4), rect);
return Path()
..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndCorners(r, topLeft: Radius.circular(4), topRight: Radius.circular(4)));
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a custom paint

```
TabBar(
  indicator: MyCustomIndicator(color: Colors.red, height: 10, radius: 10),
  ...  
)
```

**Custom Paint**

```
class MyCustomIndicator extends Decoration {
  final BoxPainter _painter;

  MyCustomIndicator(
      {@required Color color, @required double height, @required double radius})
      : _painter = _IndicatorPainter(color, height, radius);

  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([onChanged]) => _painter;
}

class _IndicatorPainter extends BoxPainter {
  final Paint _paint;
  final double radius;
  final double height;

  _IndicatorPainter(Color color, this.height, this.radius)
      : _paint = Paint()
          ..color = color
          ..isAntiAlias = true;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg) {
    final Rect rect = (offset + Offset(0, cfg.size.height - height) &
        Size(cfg.size.width, height));

    canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndCorners(rect,
          topLeft: Radius.circular(radius), topRight: Radius.circular(radius)),
      _paint,
    );
  }
}
```